# Shall go build be run always from the folder of the main package if I want to build an executable?

Tags: go, go-build

I have a simple question on the build process in Go.

I have a very simple app, the simplest possible, which is structured like this

```
- myapp
  - main
    - main.go
  - go.mod
```

with main.go being

```
package main
import "fmt"
func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello !")
}
```

From within the folder `myapp` I run the command `go build -o bin/main main/main.go` and everything works.

No I decide to create a new function `doStuff()` in the package `main` to be called by `main()` but I want to have it in a different file `stuff.go`. So the new structure of the app is

```
- myapp
  - main
    - main.go
    - stuff.go
  - go.mod
```

with `main.go` being

```
package main
import "fmt"
func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello !")
    doStuff()
}
```

and `stuff.go` being

```
package main
import "fmt"
func doStuff() {
    fmt.Println("I am doing stuff")
}
```

If I try now to run the same build command `go build -o bin/main main/main.go` I get an error `main/main.go:4:2: undefined: doStuff`.

But if I move into the `main` folder and run from there the command `go build -o ../bin/main` everything works.

Which is the reason of this behaviour? Shall I always run the `go build` command from the folder where `main()` is if i want to create an executable?

Comment: Go's compilation unit is a package, not a file, so it is rarely correct to specify filenames on the command line. Run `go build -o bin/main ./main`.

Comment: Thanks. I was brought to specify the file name by the fact that the template provided by the serverless framework for lambda functions in Go actually uses the file name in the build command. Now it is clear.

Answer (score -1):

If package `main` is split into multiple files, you can do either of the following:

```
go build -o bin/main ./main
```

or

```
go build -o bin/main ./main/*
```

Main packages are typically very small. All business logic tends to either be in `pkg/` or `internal/`.

Comment: The last one is plain wrong: Think about *_test.go or *_windows.go files.

Comment: I stated you can do it. Works as per the question is asked. You should not have unit tests for your main pkg, as mentioned in my answer, business logic is elsewhere. Thanks

Comment: Furthermore, the command works perfectly fine with *_test.go in /main dir. Sorry but you are incorrect there.